# Ways of handling isNull() method in JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json, wcf

I am facing a serious problem when parsing some json data from server. When it server returns some json data my program handle it well .But when the server returns null, my app gives me exceptions.

I have search many questions and answers. Maximum answers are saying to use isNull() method to handle the null return type for JSON. But before writing isNull method we have to write

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject("returned string");
```

this sentence is worked fine when there is data for parsing, but it gives me Exception when the string is null.

I think my question may be make some confusion to understand. So I am giving a bit of my code here.

```
    URL Url = new URL(URL + "?userId=3");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.connect();
    // gets the server json data

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));


    String next = "";

    while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(next);
        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) 
             {
          Log.d("Tokens", tokens.nextToken());
         }

       Log.d("next value", next);

       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(next);
       if (json.isNull("Location")) {

       Log.d("Json is null", "Ok");
       serverLatitude = String.valueOf(lati);
       serverLongitude = String.valueOf(longi);
           }
           else {

        Log.d("Json not null", "Ok");
        lat = json.getString("Latitude");
        lon = json.getString("Longitude");

        if (lat != null && lon != null) {
        serverLatitude = lat;
        serverLongitude = lon;

        } else {

               }
          }
```

When there is data in server it works fine.But when the server returns null it give me error.So can anyone help me how i hanle this problem

**Edit**

This is the logcat when the server returns null.

```
  08-26 14:53:22.996: D/Tokens(31397): null
  08-26 14:53:22.996: D/next value(31397): null
  08-26 14:53:22.996: D/Here lat(31397): 12.90871405
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397): org.json.JSONException: Value null of type          org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at      org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:107)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>   (JSONObject.java:158)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.fetchLastInsertedRow(NewService.java:264)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.insertDataToServer(NewService.java:126)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.onPostExecute(NewService.java:108)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.onPostExecute(NewService.java:1)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
  08-26 14:53:22.996: W/System.err(31397):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/System.err(31397):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: D/AndroidRuntime(31397): Shutting down VM
  08-26 14:53:23.006: W/dalvikvm(31397): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.insertDataToServer(NewService.java:130)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.onPostExecute(NewService.java:108)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at com.monday.trackloc.NewService$FetchCordinates.onPostExecute(NewService.java:1)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
  08-26 14:53:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(31397):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Thank You**

Comment: can u post the logcat?

Comment: put null check before `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(next);`

Comment: How to put null check before this. When it gives error when it checks that "next" is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it in different way.But it is working fine.

I think I had to concentrate upon the string first.

The solve is like this:

```
while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

  Log.d("next value", next);
  Log.d("Here lat", String.valueOf(lati));
  if (!next.contentEquals("null")) {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(next);
  Log.d("Json not null", "Ok");
  serverLatitude = json.getString("Latitude");
  serverLongitude = json.getString("Longitude");

      } else {
    emptyRow = true;
    Log.d("Json is null", "Ok");
    serverLatitude = String.valueOf(lati);
    serverLongitude = String.valueOf(longi);
    }
}
```

I saw that actually the returning string contains "null". So I just put the "null" in a if condition and now it perfectlly works.

I know this is not the perfect way to solve this problem. If any one has any good solutions for this problem ,please provide here. Thank you

Comment: Ranji, just an out of topic question. Are you part of the renegade X development team?

Comment: Sorry Brian. I don't know about "renegade X development team".